# Opencart error while uploading on server

Tags: php, opencart, smarty

I have installed Opencart on localhost it's working properly but when I have uploading on server it's give me error:

```
Cannot find template file 'default/template/module/magikslider.tpl' in /home/xyz/public_html/xyz/system/engine/factory.php on line 614
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have set a default theme, you need to apply a custom template from admin panel.

To apply template use below procedure

If you are using Opencart version 2.1.x,

- Go to **OpenCart admin panel > System > Settings > Edit**. Click Store tab and choose theme
  for "Template" option. This action will activate your new theme.

If you are using Opencart version 2.2.0.0,

- Go to **OpenCart admin panel > Extensions > Themes > Edit** and choose theme for **"Theme
  Directory"** option. This action will activate your new theme.